# Mongodb - How to use $inc if the element is not in database

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

So I have a weird issue where it actually worked before but not I do just get:

```
pymongo.errors.WriteError: Cannot create field 'test' in element {raffleItem: []}
```

So before I explain the code more, my code looks like:

```
    #email_raffleItem.raffleItem -> "TEST"
    #email_raffleItem.email -> "hello@gmail.com"

if db.license.find_one({'email': email_raffleItem.email}):
    db.license.update_one({
        'email': email_raffleItem.email
    },
        {'$inc': {
            'raffleItem.{}.entries'.format(email_raffleItem.raffleItem): 1
        }
        }, upsert=False
    )

    return db.license.find_one({'email': email_raffleItem.email}).get('raffleItem').get(
        email_raffleItem.raffleItem).get('entries')
```

And the database is as simple as:

```
{
    "email": "hello@gmail.com",
    },
    "raffleItem": []
}
```

So what it supposed to do is that whatever I write in `#email_raffleItem.raffleItem` etc the word TEST - it should automatic add into the database -> raffleItem a value of TEST which will add also a new element called entries and it will have a value 1. So a database should look like:

```
{
  "email": "hello@gmail.com",

},
"raffleItem": [
  {
    "TEST": [ { "entries": "1"} ]
  }
]
}
```

I think something like that I would say

However it worked before but now whenever I run my code it only returns the error. What am I doing wrong?

Update:

Currently how it looks from srinivasy's bulk_update::

[image: Yes]

---

How I want it to look:

[image: yess]

Comment: An array would've either elements or objects, atleast be empty but can't be like this `"TEST": [
      "entries": "1"
    ]`, So is it `"TEST": [
     { "entries": "1"}
    ]` ?

Comment: Oh yeah, I must have been doing wrong when trying to create a outprint of a DB. But yeah. As you mentioned with `"TEST": [ { "entries": "1"} ]` is correct @srinivasy

Comment: So you wanted to push this `{
    "TEST": [ { "entries": "1"} ]
  }` if it's not there or else you wanted to increment `entries` by some value if `TEST.entries` already exists in `raffleItem` ?

Comment: Exactly, So meaning if the raffleItem is empty. Then I would like to push `{ "TEST": [ { "entries": "1"} ] }` and if the value already exist then I just want to add +1 on entries if we are locating TEST.entries through code of course

Comment: But yes, Basically if its not there then I want to increment the entries by doing `raffleItem.TEST.entries` kind of that way.

Comment: your mongoDB version ?

Comment: @srinivasy I have no idea, I created an account like 1 week ago. - MongoDB 4.0.13 Enterprise

Comment: @srinivasy Does it matter if I have done `db.license.create_index('email', unique=True)` previous?

Comment: not sure how this operation is dependent on an unique index on `email` but in general it would be helpful to have a proper index, yes if `email` is unique you can create it..

Comment: @srinivasy I have done it but reading through documents and everything else. The code I have about $inc seems to be correct and I can't figure out what else I am doing wrong here :( Hopefully you could help my day to be saved before the new year!

Comment: I tried to change manually to `{ "$inc" : { "raffleItem" : { "profile" : 10, "data" : "X"}}` and that returns me `pymongo.errors.WriteError: Cannot increment with non-numeric argument: {raffleItem: { profile: 10, data: "X" }}` - something is indeed wrong with DB? @srinivasy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205095/discussion-between-srinivasy-and-thrillofit86).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this error : 
`pymongo.errors.WriteError: Cannot create field 'test' in element {raffleItem: []}` , it's because you're trying to do `$inc` on an array field that too by passing an object, additionally when you do increment on `{"entries": "1"}` value of `entries` should be a number but not a string. In your case since you've only one object in `raffleItem` & also in `TEST` you could try below query to make things work for either a push or an increment :

```
db.yourCollectionName.bulkWrite([
    {
        updateOne:
        {
            "filter": { "email": "hello@gmail.com", 'raffleItem.TEST.entries': { $exists: true } },
            "update": { $inc: { "raffleItem.$.TEST.$[].entries": 1 } }
        }
    },
    {
        updateOne:
        {
            "filter": { "email": "hello@gmail.com", 'raffleItem.TEST.entries': {$exists : false} },
            "update": {
                $set: {
                    "raffleItem": [
                        {
                            "TEST": [
                                {
                                    "entries": 1
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

In the query you need to replace `TEST` with your input variables, If you trigger `TEST1` & `TEST2` once while `TEST` thrice, then :

**Output :**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0a3509400289966e5f8014"),
    "email" : "hello@gmail.com",
    "raffleItem" : [
        {
            "TEST2" : [ 
                {
                    "entries" : 1.0
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "TEST1" : [ 
                {
                    "entries" : 1.0
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "TEST" : [ 
                {
                    "entries" : 3.0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Ref :** [.bulkwrite()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/index.html)

**For python ref :** [PyMongo-bulkwrite](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/bulk.html)

Comment: Alright so I tried to apply this to pymongo and it seems like many object such as `updateOne` `$set` withotu any quotes gives me an error even though the documentation does say it should be like you wrote. I am not able to reproduce this to work.

Comment: @Thrillofit86 : I’ve given this query for mongodb but for pymongo it’s UpdateOne

Comment: Yupp, Also I believe I need to change $set to `"$set"` aswell ?

Comment: However this returns `TypeError: {<class 'pymongo.operations.UpdateOne'>: {'filter': {'email': 'hello@gmail.com', 'raffleItem.TEST.entries': {'$exists': True}}, 'update': {'$inc': {'raffleItem.0.TEST.0.entries': 1}}}} is not a valid request`

Comment: The pymongo syntax for `bulk_write` is a different to the mongodb shell. See my answer for a pymongo version.

Comment: It seems to work kinda of buut not really how I wished. I have updated my thread with some screenshots, Please if you guys can look maybe you guys have a idea? @BellyBuster

Comment: The problem is that it converts my array to object which will results to give me error `ValueError: [KeyError(<class 'bson.objectid.ObjectId'>), TypeError("'ObjectId' object is not iterable"), TypeError('vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute')]`

Answer (score 1):

Pymongo version of srinivasy's bulk_update:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import UpdateOne

db = pymongo.MongoClient()['mydatabase']

db.yourCollectionName.bulk_write([
    UpdateOne(
        {"email": "hello@gmail.com", 'raffleItem.TEST.entries': {"$exists": True}},
        {"$inc": {"raffleItem.0.TEST.0.entries": 1}}
    ),
    UpdateOne(
        {"email": "hello@gmail.com", "raffleItem": []},
        {"$set": {
            "raffleItem": [
                {
                    "TEST": [
                        {
                            "entries": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
        })
])
```

Comment: It seems to kinda work - I do still get the `ValueError: [KeyError(<class 'bson.objectid.ObjectId'>), TypeError("'ObjectId' object is not iterable"), TypeError('vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute')]` of this code HOWEVER it does att in database - Will update a picture in the thread